# Selecting different rows from two different tables in one query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I'm trying to build a query to select multiple rows from two different tables. However the tables both have different rows.

It's should be something like this (probally should use the JOIN function):

```
SELECT `a`, `b`, `c`, `d` FROM table1 AND `e`, `f`, `g`, `h` FROM table2 WHERE `a` = `e`
```

Any idea how to achieve this?

Comment: `UNION ALL` if you want multiple rows `SELECT a, b, c, d FROM table1 UNION ALL e, f, g, h FROM table2`

Comment: Is there any relation bw the tables?

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Show your real schema rather than fake data, whether you want to have them side by side (join) or one after each other (Union) - you say yourself you should probably use join. Well search for sql join, 63 million examples out there.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because no schema, no sample data, no expected results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use either a Join or a Union, preferably a Join.

If you want to return lets say columns "1" and "2" in table "a" and columns "3" and "4" in table "b" use the following:

SELECT 1.a, 2.a, 3.b, 4.b FROM a join b ON key.a = key.b;

a and b refer to table names
1,2,3,4 refer to the attribute you wish to return.
key is the Primary and foreign key for your tables, essentially a shared column

You could also use a Union between two select statements, each selecting the appropriate data from a single table but the join is generally the way to go

For your example, the following would work:
SELECT a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h from table1 join table2;
If however you had a repeated attribute in both tables such as id or name, you would have to specify id.table1, id.table2, name.table1, name.table2 etc